# Environment variables not being appearing correctly in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, psql

Trying to add a database by the name of abc but postgresql instead creates a database called NEW_DATABASE.

```
export NEW_DATABASE=abc
psql -U postgres -c 'create database "$NEW_DATABASE";'
```

Omitting the double quotes gives an error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$"
LINE 1: create database $NEW_DATABASE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
psql -U postgres -c 'create database "$NEW_DATABASE";'
```

With:

```
psql -U postgres -c "create database \"$NEW_DATABASE\";"
```

The problem is that shell variables are not expanded inside single-quotes.  If you want shell variables expanded, use double-quotes.